# Problems on MySQL installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, mysql, oracle-database

Well, I've installed MySQL Server 8.0 on Windows 10 a few months ago, but I've lost the root password.

On a desperate rush to uninstall it and install again, I've uninstalled using CCleaner and manually deleted every registry on Windows REGEDIT with any mention of "mysql", but now, I've remembered root password (I've set it to login root, password root :C).

Now, I'm trying to install all over again, but the services don't run and the "Starting Server" step is down in the error:

```
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Please, can anyone tell me how to fix all registry entrys or completely remove all MySQL from my computer to install a clean MySQL?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Also, I've uninstalled Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, now I cant uninstall Mysql for Visual Studio either

Comment: Just an comment, but I would 1) make sure any MySQL services were stopped 2) Look in `C:/ProgramData` for any MySQL databases and move them somewhere else (assuming you might want whatever information is contained in them) 3) Try using Add/Remove Programs to uninstall whatever you currently have installed 4) Try reinstalling MySQL. You may want to have a look at the section on installing MySQL manually from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1435320/apachephpmysql-for-latest-windows-10/1435495#1435495) if you just want a working installation.

Comment: Thanks @Anaksunaman, I've got it done xD

Comment: Good to hear. =)