# MySQL 8.0.16 Community Edition install stopping at "Starting the Server" step on Windows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to install MySQL 8.0.16 Community Server on Windows 10.  I keep getting to the "Apply Configuration" step, I hit 'Execute", and then I get to the "Starting the Server" step and it fails and tells me to look at the log.  This is what the log says:

Beginning configuration step: Starting the server

```
Attempting to start service MySQL80...
Successfully started service MySQL80.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.16 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.16 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting the server
```

I did set up a password, so I am not sure why it says no password in the log.
I am trying to install this for work, so if someone has some advice it would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check whether MySQL or anything else is listening on port 3306?

Comment: I am so sorry to ask, I am really not good with things like this, but how woud I go about checking that?  I can certainly try!

Comment: So I checked it and it says "LISTENING", but that's all I can see about it.

Comment: `netstat -aon | findstr LISTEN`. What I'm saying is that maybe the service fails to start because ports 3306 is already bound to a different process. It may be an instance of the same program (MySQL) or another program (more unlikely).

Comment: When I checked it MySQL was running.  So I ended the process and tried again and it still wouldn't work.  I did this a few times.

Comment: @CarlyGiblets As a suggestion, if you just want the server to run, you may want to take a look at the manual configuration steps in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1435320/apachephpmysql-for-latest-windows-10/1435495#1435495). Basically, in step 3, if the Online Transaction Processing (OLTP) number isn't set to the default of `Up to 500 connections`, you may get the exact problem you are encountering. This can happen if you aren't doing a manual installation as well (i.e. you are letting the installer configure things for you).

Answer (score 0):

You may try getting through the setup by not configuring additional settings and just setting up the InnoDB, install location etc. Try installing it that way. Password can be set from within MySQL 
Use this command to create user and set password

```
>Create user 'any name'@'your host';
>Alter user 'any name'@'your host' identified by 'the password';
```

Use this one to set privileges

```
>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your name'@'your host' identified by 'your password';
```

Check hosts with:

```
>SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;
```

Most likely your host is 'localhost' so you can replace `'your host'` in the above queries with `localhost`.
Just try running the setup without going through additional configuration.

Comment: Same kind of problem arose with me during MySQL Community Server 5.5 install and I got through it this way. 

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in the configuration stage post installation of mysql.
I had renamed the windows service from `MySQL80` to `MySQL Server 80`. I went back and reverted the service name in MySQL installer. 
This error resolved. 
I also went to service.msc and disabled the duplicate service `MySQL Server 80` since `MySQL80` service had also been created.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix it is to cancel the installation at that point and then just open the mySQL Workbench.

From there you click Local Instance MySQL80 (or whatever it it called for you). Usually this prompts for a password but if you are experiencing this error it wont.

Notice the navigator on the left and click "Users and Privileges". From there select "root" and it will give you the option to change the password. Change the password, apply and restart mySQL. Issue fixed!

Tldr: Quit installation -> Open MySQL Workbench -> Local Insrance -> Users and Privileges -> root -> Change password, apply and restart